# Difference between "page.should_not have_content" and "page.should have_no_content"

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara

Can anybody explain me the difference between "page.should_not have_content" and "page.should have_no_content" in capybara and which one is the better option to ensure page does not have a specific content?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming Capybara::RSpecMatchers has been included correctly there is no real difference in the two methods you're asking about, they both boil down to running `current_scope_element.assert_no_text(...)`

Comment: So, one is not better over another?

Comment: @AJ nope - they both do the same thing, pick the one you prefer.  The only technical difference would be the error messages produced in case of failure.